# Terminal command to check for iOS updates

Tags: ios, itunes, command-line, upgrade

I have an iPhone paired with iTunes on my MacBook, and I would like to use Terminal to check whether an iOS update is available for that iPhone (using the last known state if the phone is not connected).

Is there a Terminal command that can do that?

Comment: When all one has to do it look at the Setting icon on the iPhone to see if an update is available or not, I fail to see why one needs to use Terminal to determine this. That said, the only info I can think of you can get from Terminal is the Product Version from the Info.plist file(s) from the MobileSync Backup(s). This of course could be dated info depending on how long it's been and if you've actually updated the iOS since the last MobileSync Backup. Anyway, just for the heck of it here's the command: `for f in $HOME/L*/A*/M*/B*/*/Info.plist; do defaults read "$f" "Product Version"; done`

Comment: I never have the Settings icon in view, or open the Settings app if I can help it.  The update notifications always interrupt me actually using my phone for something, and they don't sit in my notifications list so they're basically useless.  I want a notification that isn't useless, and I can do that with a shell script, if there is a command that can check for updates.

Comment: Showing the backup versions could be part of a solution, but they would have to be checked against the current version read somehow from Apple.  (That approach would end up being a notification that backups are old and/or a new version is available since the last backup, which isn't quite what I was asking, but would work for me.)